# How to get index where record is at

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a field called 'points' in my user table,
And they are ranked according to how high their points are, the person with the highest points is rank #1.

How would I order members by the 'points' in DESC order, then get what index a player is at, so I can rank them from that?
I used a loop for my ranks page but I can't really loop through each player for this..
I am using PDO.

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT count(points) FROM members WHERE id = {$id}");

$rank = mysql_result($q, 0, 0) + 1;
```

Is the code I have, but my problem is that it's in mysql_, which I need it in PDO and I'm not sure how to do this because the mysql_result has lost some parameters in pdo (->fetchColumn I believe)

another attempt to explain it:
I want to order the users in order by their points in descending order, then use the ROW NUMBER as their rank, how do I get their raw row number?

Comment: Add code and what do you use to connect to mysql via php(`PDO`, `mysql_*`, `mysqli_*`)?

Comment: I don't have any code, I stated that I was using a loop for my other ranking thing but then I realised it wouldn't work for freely getting a random players rank, only showing the 'top x' in points. I am using PDO

Comment: @bloodless2010   hurrrr   you have no code, no errors and no table design ???   how do you expect people to answer your question then? also what you mean by index, if you order by, then the top result will always be index[0]  I.E  first record in array, second place would be the second in array and so on

Comment: @davethecoder You don't understand  what I mean, I'm ordering in DESC so you have the correct order so the index will be in the right place.. If it was all over the place their rank wouldn't corrospond to their index. I'll update OP with a mysql_* version, but i need it in pdo :/

Comment: your last amend, is your actual question really, rather than another way of explaining things. this would be in your for loop in your page, where the index on your loop, is the number +1 for your ranking text value to display.   this has nothing to do with SQL code or the content of that query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is to have an inner query that ranks the result set, then the outer query limits the result set to the user whose rank you need. like:

```
/* Assuming the users' table is "members" and it contains the field "points" */
SELECT mo.* , (
    SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM members mi
    WHERE mi.points >= mo.points  // >= for desc order, <= to for ascending order
) AS rank
FROM members mo
WHERE id = @id                    // Replace @id with the id
```

The row number/their rank will be the rank field in the result.

Outside Note: You don't want to do `mo.*` as in the query above but rather select the specific columns you need in your resultset.... `SELECT mo.id, mo.name, ...`